# How to read a socket command sent by VB.NET to Android?

Tags: android, vb.net, sockets

I'm trying to send some commands to Android (client) from VB.NET (server) using sockets. I can connect the client to the server, but I don't know how to receive the commands sent by the server.

Here's a part of my Android code:

```
public void connect(View v){ //called on button click
    SERVER_IP = ip.getText().toString(); //it gets the server's ip from an editText
    SERVER_PORT = Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString()); //and the port too
    Toast.makeText(this, "Trying to connect to\n" + SERVER_IP + ":" + SERVER_PORT + "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            InetAddress serverAddr;
            try {
                serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT); //It establishes the connection with the server

                if(socket != null && socket.isConnected()){ //not sure if it is correct
                    BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                    //Here comes the problem, I don't know what to add...

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }).start();       
}
```

And here's a part of my VB.NET send code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    send(TextBox1.text)
End Sub

Private Sub Send(ByVal command)
    Dim temp() As Byte = UTF8.GetBytes(command) 'Is UTF8 right to use for that?
    stream.Write(temp, 0, temp.Length)
    stream.Flush()
End Sub
```

Question1: is it right to us UTF8 instead of for example ASCII encoding?

Question2: what would I change in the Android code if it wanted to use a timer that sends a command every second?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read input from a BufferedReader you need to do something similiar to this:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String line;
while((line = input.readLine()) != null){
    // do something with the input here
}
```

A nice tutorial on sockets is available from oracle in the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

The default charset on Android is UTF-8 http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html, so no worries there but you can always send a byte stream from the server onto the client and decode it however you want.

To receive a byte stream you need to do this:

```
BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
byte[] buffer = new byte[byteCount];
while(input.read(buffer, 0, byteCount) != -1 ){
     // do something with the bytes
     // for example decode it to string
     String decoded = new String(buffer, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
     // keep in mind this string might not be a complete command it's just a decoded byteCount number of bytes
}
```

As you see it's much easier if you send strings instead of bytes.

If you want to receive input from the server periodically, one of the solutions would be to create a loop which opens a socket, receives input, process it, closes the socket, and then repeats, our you could just keep the loop running endlessly until some command like "STOP" is received.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've just tried both of them. The firt one, as I understand, is used for one command/message only and then you have to close the connection. Am I right? The second one is used like in my case. Infact it works perfectly. But now I have only one question more: is there any way to get the buffersize before reading the command/message? Now I'm using a constant because I know the maximum number of byte, but what if the commands were of differents lenghts?

Comment: That's the thing, you can't know unless your are coding both the server and the client, that why it's trickier to send bytes. to make sure everything gets through correctly you would need to read bytes from the BufferedInputStream, allocate a new byte array which is equal to all the bytes received so far + the new bytes, store the new bytes in that array, and when you receive all the bytes, decode the String from that complete byte array.